# Programa em python que atualiza pasta de arquivos automaticamente

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um algorítimo em python que sempre que disponibilizo uma versão nova de arquivos(ps. esses arquivos seriam armazenados no sd card, portanto não são parte funcional do algorítimo), pode ser no github, ou em algum site hospedado, o algorítimo verifica  a versão disponível e a versão que está na pasta e atualize os arquivos no sd, por enquanto estou somente na fase de rabiscar como o algorítimo vai funcionar, porém não conheço nenhum módulo que possa me ajudar, dei uma olhada no pip e git mas sem sucesso, alguém conhece algo que eu possa utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para fazer seu algoritmo utilize os módulos "socket" e "os".
O módulo "socket" irá te ajudar a conectar a algum servidor remoto.
O módulo "os" irá te ajudar a conversar com o sistema operacional para fazer a atualização dos arquivos nas pastas, use "Batch Script" com os.system() para fazer isso.